# Brightness keys repeat many times after released

Tags: boot, hardware

I've ran into this issue where the *brightness control* on my laptop will "repeat" for a second or so, even when tapped lightly.

The shortcuts are `Fn+Home` and `Fn+End` on this LG Z1 Pro Express Dual.

**What I tried:**

There is no `Fn` lock. I tried toggling the BIOS setting for "sticky `Fn` key" either way, with no result.

While the brightness adjustment is *going on* in these repeated little stages (like 5 FPS) the window manager is absolutely unresponsive, and takes a few seconds to come back. Can't even move the mouse while it's happening.

**Update:** I added `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to GRUB configuration, and now it doesn't repeat quite as much. Still goes 5 FPS while the display is "fading" and the indicator overlay is showing. Maybe it's not repeating, just tries to fade smoothly to new values and is really slow at doing that?
Doesn't seem to have a problem doing all the other compositing stuff though.

Comment: The updated .4 did not address this. I have a feeling there are some slow memory copying going on upstream, possibly.